# Enviar consulta SQL Server a la vista en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Buen día a todos

He realizado una consulta en ASP.NET MVC con SQL SERVER, que me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo con el que hago la consulta es el siguiente:

```
 public ActionResult EmbarcacionesAreaTiempo(int? id, DateTime fentrada, DateTime fsalida, int? tiempo)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Close();
            ViewBag.band = 0;
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Close();
            db.Database.Connection.Open();

            db.Database.CommandTimeout = 60000;
            //en sql server 2012 en adelante
            //string query = "with R as (select *, row_number() over(partition by VesselName order by EntryTime desc, ReportingPointID desc) as rn from Reporting) select * from R where rn = 1 and ReportingPointID=10 and ExitTime IS NULL order by EntryTime desc  OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY";

            //en sql server 2000 al 2008 en adelante
            string query = "SET LANGUAGE SPANISH SELECT VesselName, MMSI, ResponsibilityAreaName, EntrySpeed, ExitSpeed,EntryTime,ExitTime, DATEDIFF(Day, EntryTime, ExitTime) As Dias, DATEDIFF (Hour, EntryTime, ExitTime) % 24 As Horas, DATEDIFF (Minute, EntryTime, ExitTime) % 60 As Minutos, DATEDIFF (Second, EntryTime, ExitTime) % 60 As Segundos FROM[KNC_OMIS_PEMEX].[dbo].[Reporting] as Report, [KNC_OMIS_PEMEX].[dbo].[Responsibility_Area] as Respon where Report.ReportingPointID = Respon.ResponsibilityAreaID and ResponsibilityAreaName = {0} and(EntryTime >= {1} and EntryTime <= {2}) and((DATEDIFF(Minute, EntryTime, ExitTime) % 60 >= {3}) or(DATEDIFF(Hour, EntryTime, ExitTime) % 24 >= '1'))";


            var report = db.Reportings.SqlQuery(query, id, fentrada, fsalida, tiempo).ToList();

            db.Database.Connection.Close();
            ViewBag.band = 1;
            return View(report);
        }
    }
```

Lo que necesito es ¿Como mando los campos generados en la tabla a la vista?
Utilizo ASP.NET MVC (Visual Studio 2019) y SQL SERVER

Les agradezco de antemano el apoyo

saludos y gracias

Comment: Pero cuál es el problema? No los recibes? Los recibes mal? No sabes como recibirlos?

Comment: Gracias Paulo la pregunta es.. ¿como recibo todos esos campos, si el campo: "Dias", "Horas", "Minutos", "Segundos" no existen en la tabla, fueron generados en la consulta,  ¿como los mando a la vista y como los muestro en la vista?

Comment: Lee la parte donde muestra los datos en el siguiente articulo: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Show-data-records-from-Database-Table-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: Gracias por comentar Miguel, pero el link que me envías no me dice como mostrar un campo que es calculado en la vista, solo me esta mostrando en la vista los campos que son parte de la tabla, excepto: Dias, Horas, Minutos y Segundos, los cuales son calculados y como no están en la tabla no me los muestra la vista, ¿La pregunta es: como los visualizo en la vista?

Comment: Da lo mismo lo que generes o lo que no en el back, todo (o casi) se puede recibir en el front utilizando $.ajax, react, angular, etc... Tienes desarrollada esa parte?

Comment: Gracias Paulo, no Paulo no la tengo desarrollada, los datos los traigo con Razor, me puedes ayudar como los traigo con $.ajax de Jquery por ejemplo? o algún ejemplo que tengas o link donde lo explique.